# Задание из Яндекс Практикума по Python, Декораторы

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

"**Задание:** Напишите функцию-декоратор, которая сохранит (закеширует) значение декорируемой функции.
Если декорируемая функция будет вызвана повторно с теми же параметрами — декоратор должен вернуть сохранённый результат, не выполняя функцию.

**Подсказка:** Создайте словарь и при каждом вызове декоратора сохраняйте в нём аргументы задекорированной функции.
При каждом вызове проверяйте, не было ли уже аналогичного вызова.
Если был — верните результат прошлого вызова, если не было — верните результат декорируемой функции и одновременно сохраните этот результат в словарь.
Ключом для каждой записи словаря может быть аргумент декорируемой функции."

Собственно, код. Написать требуется функцию cache_args, но как ни бьюсь — она работает неверно.

```
import time
from functools import wraps


def time_check(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        execution_time = round(time.time() - start_time, 1)
        print(f'Время выполнения функции {func.__name__}: {execution_time} с.')
        return result

    return wrapper



def cache_args(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper1(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        x = []
        for t in x:
            if t == result:
                return t
        x = x.append(result)
        return result
    return wrapper1


@time_check
@cache_args
def long_heavy(num):
    time.sleep(1)
    return num * 2


print(long_heavy(1))
# Время выполнения функции long_heavy: 1.0 с.
# 2
print(long_heavy(1))
# Время выполнения функции long_heavy: 0.0 с.
# 2
print(long_heavy(2))
# Время выполнения функции long_heavy: 1.0 с.
# 4
print(long_heavy(2))
# Время выполнения функции long_heavy: 0.0 с.
# 4
print(long_heavy(2))
# Время выполнения функции long_heavy: 0.0 с.
# 4
```

Comment: В подсказке написано создать словарь и хранить там аргументы. А у вас этого нет. У вас везде один аргумент. Вам действительно нужно обрабатывать все арги и кварги? И помнить надо все предыдущие запуски функции, или только предыдущий?

Comment: @Alpensin x = x.append(result) не дополняет словарь аргументами, получается? Насчет аргов и кваргов не знаю, сделал по аналогии с уже заданной time_check. Судя по заданию, помнить надо все результаты, но если исходить из проверок — то хватит и только предыдущего (и это закодить будет гораздо проще, как мне кажется).

Comment: @Crystallice Не надо упрощать, там и так проще некуда всё. Вы хотя бы разницу между словарём и списком понимаете? `[]` - это `list`, т.е. список. И инициализировать кэш надо вне `wrapper1`, иначе при каждом вызове `wrapper1` он у вас будет сбрасываться. И `func` надо вызывать не всегда, а только если результат её вызова с таким же аргументом не закэширован.

Comment: То есть, я правильно понимаю, что при вызове cache_args будет выполняться только wrapper1, и если словарь определить в cashe_args, то он перезаписываться каждый раз не будет?

Comment: @CrazyElf
Если мы упростим, то достаточно будет хранить cache = {'arg': arg, 'result': result}. Если с args и kwargs, то для сравнения старых и новых аргументов нам достаточно будет сделать проверку cache['old_args'] == args and cache['old_kwargs'] == kwargs. Если мы будем хранить всю историю вызовов, то в значениях словаря уже будут списки из args, kwargs и result соответственно. Такая логика?

Comment: @Alpensin Ну, почти так. Только словарь в принципе такой `{arg: result}` и проверка `if arg in cache:` В принципе, можно с аргументами не заморачиваться и тупо сделать ключ словаря `key = f'{args}{kwargs}'`, и будет работать с любыми аргументами.

Comment: Я предложил рабочий код, который проходит тесты в тренажёре. Так канечно есть что улучшать.

Answer (score 0):

```
cache = {}

def cache_args(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper1(*args, **kwargs):
        if args[0] in cache:
            return cache[args[0]]
        else:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            cache[args[0]] = result
            return result
    return wrapper1
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `с теми же параметрами` поэтому только по `args[0]` неправильно рассчитывать. Как вариант, можно попробовать все значения `args` и `kwargs` представить в виде строки и ее в ключ положить

Comment: Еще можно попробовать избавиться глобальной переменной `cache = {}` поместив ее в саму функцию-декоратор: `def cache_args(func):` `if not hasattr(cache_args, 'cache'):` `cache_args.cache = dict()` и далее работать с `cache_args.cache`. Проверить можно после создания и выполнения функций с тем декоратором и выведя `print(cache_args.cache)`

Answer (score 0):

Я написал чуть короче:

```
cache = {}

def cache_args(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):           
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[args]
    return wrapper
```

Возможно это и не очень грамотно с точки зрения реальных проектов, но для решения учебной задачи ИМХО достаточно.